# Why do browsers with an "offline" option still behave mostly like apps "online"?

Tags: express, networking, browser, socket.io, google-chrome-devtools

tl;dr: what's the logic behind browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari) behaving as an app that's online after clicking offline and not simply... go offline?

## CPP, FOP, STP

I have a small socket.io app that fetches from Twitter's API to make an image gallery.

I wanted to style the the `div`s that create a frame around the photos, but while the app is running found out that when selecting the elements in the dev tools, whenever a new image was added, Chrome emits a "purple 
 pulsing" (hereafter referred to as CPP) that kicked me out of the `div` I *wanted* to style and (rudely) put me at its parent `div` (the Gallery proper, if you will).

Voilà:

[image: Chrome's Purple Pulse]

I started by shutting off my WiFi, which solved the problem with two drawbacks:

- remembered the offline option in the network panel
- needed a connection to read the [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/#What-Socket-IO-is) docs :~)

Next I tried the offline option and found that, like the production version, CPP reëmerged, the image requests logging  `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`.

I realized that I could probably set the option `reconnection: false` in the socket.io bit but alas, this novella of question (which contains multitudes) still beckoned:

## The Actual Question(s)

What chez Google (and Firefox (Orange Pulse), Safari (Transparent Pulse), et. al) is the logic to this behavior?

Why not Truly Sever the relevant tab's connection?

Better yet, why not let the poor developer both hold fast to their element *and* acknowledge visually that new elements are being thrown in?

The images are still fetched (!) which makes the Offline option seem even more misleading.

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#offline) from Google reference PWAs and those with service workers... does

> Check the Offline checkbox to simulate a completely offline network experience.

apply only to them?

## The Code that Kinda Could:

Here are the ~20 relevant lines at play ([and here's the whole gig](https://github.com/saylestyler/magallery)):

```
// app.js

var T = new Twit(config)

var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#MyHashtag', })

stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) { io.sockets.emit('tweet', tweet) })

function handler(request, response) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html')
    stream.pipe(response)
}
```

... and the `index.html`'s relevant script:

```
// index.html

var socket = io.connect('/');

socket.on('tweet', function(tweet) {
    if (someConditions = foo) {
        tweet_container.innerHTML = '<img src="' 
            + tweet.user.profile_image_url +
        '" />'
    }
}, 1000)
```

*Nota Bene*: I realize this question contains questions germane to polling, streams, networking, and topics whose names I'm not even familiar with, but my primary curiosity is *what's the logic behind behaving as an app that's online after clicking offline and not simply... go offline" (and behave as it does when disconnecting from WiFi).*

P.S.S here's a quote from knee-deep in the socket.io docs

> If a certain client is not ready to receive messages (because of network slowness or other issues, or because they’re connected through long polling and is in the middle of a request-response cycle), ***if it doesn’t receive ALL the tweets related to bieber your application won’t suffer***.
>
> In that case, you might want to send those messages as volatile messages.